# Deploying multiple war files with own JSF configurations

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, web.xml

I'm using Maven to deploy a Java web project into my Tomcat 6.0 server. I have a "system" named project which is a war, and has his own JSF configuration and JSF managed beans.

The goal is that this system can have some apps installed on it, and apps themselves also have their web content and JSF configuration. My problem comes here, and I have two choices.

If I compile the app as a jar file, the faces-config.xml file has to be stored in the project's META-INF folder, so when loading the jar, JSF can find this file because it's located in the default place. However, my app also have web content, and I have to store it in the main system (webapp) location if I want it to be read. That's a functional but not elegant solution.

What I want to do is to define the app as a war file, and including it into the main system POM file, every web content from my app will be published in the server automatically. That's a good idea, but what can I do with my faces-config.xml file?? I already have one defined in my system and when Maven tries to deploy it, it finds there's already a same named file into the server. So I can't get my app JSF configuration from my system.

There is a way to define multiple jsf-config files, using a context-param in web.xml. Something like that works, but I want it to be dynamic:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-managed-beans.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Does anybody have any idea for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why exactly is having JSF modules as JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` not elegant? That's exactly the solution to your problem.

Comment: Cause that modules also have web content (xhtml and css)! Is it a good choice to be extracting the content from JAR each time it changes? I was thinking it's better to compile it like a war and overlap the two projects...

Comment: Sorry, I do still not see/understand the concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

> That's a good idea, but what can I do with my faces-config.xml file?? I already have one defined in my system ...

It sounds like you should remove that copy, and put a webapp specific copy in each webapp.